# How to get a relational entity-object by Linq-to-Entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

```
 using (var dataContext = new realtydbEntities())
        {
            var user =
                (
               from aspnet_Roles rol in dataContext.aspnet_Roles.Include("aspnet_Users")
               from aspnet_Users usr in rol.aspnet_Users
               where rol.RoleId == roleID
               select usr
                );
            return user.ToList();

        }
```

I want use

> **usr.MemberShip.Email**

MemberShip is *a foreign table's foreign table*.

### aspnet_Roles->aspnet_Users->Membership.Email

but i got an error: **The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**

How can i include the membership object to the result??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most probably need to include the aspnet_Membership table that hangs off the aspnet_User table as below:

```
using (var dataContext = new realtydbEntities())
{
      var user =
      (
          from aspnet_Roles rol in dataContext.aspnet_Roles.Include("aspnet_Users")
          from aspnet_Users usr in rol.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Membership")
          where rol.RoleId == roleID
          select usr
      );
   return user.ToList();
 }
```

Comment: 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Include(bool, bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: I don't have enough information to do it myself, the include string needs to have the correct name. Can you check if that is correct based on your EF model?